# Android Room Allow Dao @Query to populate @Ignore columns

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm wanting my Dao to populate @Ignore columns in my Entity class. For example:

**Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "example")
data class Example(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long,
    val value: Int
) {
    @Ignore
    var nextId: Long = 0L
}
```

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface ExampleDao {
    @Query(value = "SELECT *, (id + 1) AS nextId FROM example")
    fun getAllExamples(): List<Example>
}
```

However, when the application gets built, the following warning gets produced:
 `The query returns some columns [nextId] which are not used by com.example.app.Example` and it doesn't populate `nextId`.

Is it possible to include @Ignore columns in a @Query (if so, how)? If not, what are some strategies that can be employed to populate columns that are not present in my tables into my Entity class.

**Note:** I'm fully aware with the example provided that I can simply do something like:

```
@Ignore
val nextId: Long = id + 1
```

But is not the point of the question I am asking.

Comment: "Is it possible to include @Ignore columns in a @Query (if so, how)?" -- AFAIK, no. "If not, what are some strategies that can be employed to populate columns that are not present in my tables into my Entity class" -- don't use your entity class. Use another POJO (or POKO, since this is Kotlin) that has `nextId` that is not marked with `@Ignore`. So, `getAllExamples()` would return `List<SomeClassThatHasNonIgnoredNextId>`.

Comment: That's a shame, do you know if it is a feature that will be worked on in the future?

Comment: I have no insights into their plans. However, I wouldn't expect it. An entity class exists to define the schema. It is a convenient thing to use for query results, but it is not a requirement for query results. What you're asking for is basically for them to add a `@IgnoreForSchemaButAllowForQueryResultsKThxBye` annotation.

Comment: That's fair, thanks for the information in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information that @CommonsWare has given me, the solution that I went with is

```
data class ExampleWithNextId(
    @Embedded
    val example: Example) {
    var nextId: Long = 0L
}
```

Then use it in Dao like so

```
@Dao
interface ExampleDao {
    @Query(value = "SELECT *, (id + 1) AS nextId FROM example")
    fun getAllExamplesWithNextId(): List<ExampleWithNextId>
}
```

Comment: This works well. Bookmarked because I'm sure in the next 2-3 years this issue will still be there